# Flow takes very long to start up because it checks node_modules

Tags: flowtype, flow-typed

I added [Flow](https://flowtype.org/) to my React/Redux/Webpack project and initially, it was great, I loved the type annotations. Over time, I noticed that the start up time of the project became really slow - around 120s; it used to be around 20s. Upon investigation, I realized that it was because Flow was scanning through all the JS files in `node_modules`.

I attempted to ignore `node_modules` in `.flowconfig` by adding:

```
[ignore]
.*node_modules/.*
```

The start up became fast again but Flow would complain `Required module not found` in places where I import external libraries from my code.

A workaround suggested in this [Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/869) was to flowignore the `node_modules` and manually add interfaces for external libraries. This seems to work but is a hassle to maintain when new libraries are added into the project.

It's frustrating to have to wait almost 2 minutes each time I start the project, are there any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to avoid the `Required module not found` errors would be to run `flow-typed install` which will fetch existing libdefs for popular libraries from the [flow-typed](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/) repository. It also generates stubs for the libraries that cannot be found in it. This works great for many projects but in some rare cases, the stubs for certain libraries like `Immutable.js` were not generated.

I eventually came up with cli command [flow-scripts](https://github.com/yangshun/flow-scripts) to automatically generate the libdef stub interfaces such that I could flowignore `node_modules` but not get the `Required module not found` errors.

Simply run

```
$ flow-scripts stub
```

in the root of the repository and the libdef stubs will be automatically generated in `flow-typed` directory.